# shortcut to close recently opened tab in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

During browsing on the google chrome, tabs gets opened when accidentally clicked on adds. I want to know if there is any shortcut to close recently opened tab.

Comment: http://productforums.google.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ctrl + w`  -> That will close last opened tab in google chrome browser.

Comment: Command + w on mac